# Simple mysqli_query SELECT returns false

Tags: php, mysql

i seriously dont understand why the following dumps me bool(false)

```html
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";


$sql = "SELECT id FROM maxims ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
var_dump(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: mysql_error() is useless. you're using mysqli, and the two libraries are NOT interchangeable/interoperable. `mysqli_error($conn)` instead, and note the `i`. Plus, you're doing your `or ` on the results of the var_dump, **NOT** the results of the query call. var_dump can't fail, therefore you'd never trigger the error output anyways.

Comment: plus, you forgot to select a database

Comment: @MarcB mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: Where do you select your database? This query is being run against the `mysql` database, then?

Comment: Ok I get now the error, no database selected. How do I fix this@tadman ? $conn is inside the query already ...

Comment: After $conn use this **mysqli_select_db($conn, "your_database_name");**

Comment: Ok works now guys, thank you very much!
Just in case sb wants to know:
mysqli_select_db($conn, dbname);

Answer (score 1):

```
 mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mydb");

 e.g

 $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','password','database1');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php